# How to prevent RadioButton unchecked once it is checked?

Tags: xaml, enums, radio-button

I've got an `enum` like this:

```
public enum DLTypeEnum
{
    Others = 1, People = 2, Company = 4,
}
```

I have a property in my `ViewModel` like this:

```
private DLTypeEnum _DLType;
public DLTypeEnum DLType
{
    get { return _DLType; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _DLType, value); }
}
```

Here is my `xaml`:

```
<WrapPanel  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
    <WrapPanel.Resources>
        <Converter:EnumToBoolConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter" />
    </WrapPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton GroupName="DLType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DLType,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dlAccount:DLTypeEnum.Others}}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="DLType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DLType,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dlAccount:DLTypeEnum.People}}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="DLType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DLType,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dlAccount:DLTypeEnum.Company}}"/>
 </WrapPanel>
```

And this converter:

```
 public class EnumToBoolConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        private int val;
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int intParam = (int)parameter;
            val = (int)value;

            return ((intParam & val) != 0);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)//bool to enum
        {
            val ^= (int)parameter;
            return Enum.Parse(targetType, val.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Once the `RadioButton` is checked, I don't want it to be unchecked unless it select the other `RadioButton` (ie. one `RadioButton` must be selected all the time).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you just need to establish they're a group via `GroupName` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745072(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_groups_with_groupname).

Comment: I still have problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<WrapPanel  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
    <WrapPanel.Resources>
        <Converter:EnumToBoolConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter" />
    </WrapPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton GroupName="DLType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DLType,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dlAccount:DLTypeEnum.Others}}" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="DLType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DLType,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dlAccount:DLTypeEnum.People}}" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="DLType" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DLType,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dlAccount:DLTypeEnum.Company}}" Unchecked="RadioButton_Unchecked"/>
 </WrapPanel>
```

And Code behind:

```
private void RadioButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if((_viewModel.DLss.CurrentItem as DL).DLType == 0)
      ((RadioButton)sender).IsChecked = true;
}
```